# Glitchy Debian Install screen - both standard and graphical

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I've been trying to install Debian and I've done the following in order to try to fix this:

[image: Both Standard and Graphical install methods have the problem]:

1. Changed USB drives.
2. Added the fb=false parameter to boot
3. Tried Testing build (stretch) and Stable build.
4. Added nomodeset to the boot parameters
5. Tried both normal and graphical install (screenshots attached)

My computer is an HP Probook 440 G2 with a core i5 and Intel HD 4400 Graphics running in UEFI mode. I need it UEFI mode since Legacy BIOS (and MBR drive partitioning) is unacceptable

Anything else I can try to get it working?

Comment: Do you get the same result with different distributions? I'd start with Ubuntu.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Kubuntu and Arch Linux multiple times over the last 3 years with no issues at all. This is the first time I'm seeing an install screen with this Glitch.

Even Kali (which is a derivative) installs without a hitch.

Comment: Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Kubuntu are also derivatives of Debian, directly or indirectly. It's strange that you are having this problem only with Debian. Whar driver does your graphics card use, and is it using the same driver in the other distributions?

Comment: @FaheemMitha From what I read on some forums the installer uses an old version of the driver and supposedly the installer also works in Legacy mode but not UEFI mode.

Comment: In that case, update the driver. :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't think I can do that to the ISO. The installer has the problem. I haven't been able to install

Comment: Oops. Sorry, that was a dumb thing to say. Though it's perfectly possible to rebuild the installer with a newer driver, I suspect it's not trivial. Ok, one thing you can do is mount the installer disk and look at what version of the drivers it is using. And again, what driver is this, please? And why not install in legacy mode and figure out how to upgrade the partitioning later? I suppose that would be GPT partitioning. At least try it in legacy mode.

Comment: This is the display driver we're talking about. Also, to convert from MBR to GPT, you need format the drives completely so I'd end up losing my install anyway.

Comment: No, I mean what is the name of the driver in question? Point taken about MBR to GPT.

Comment: This seems to come up : xserver-xorg-video-intel

This runs after the install. Don't know what runs during the installation

Comment: Yes, I guess the Intel driver makes sense for an Intel card. You should check the version on your installer vs other installers.

Comment: Something you might like to try is to boot from a Rescue CD. Prepare the disk using GPT. Remember the 1MB partition for Grub boot code. Leave most of the rest blank and unallocated. Then go back and boot from the Debian installer in Legacy mode. Allocate partitions but don't let the installer format the disk with a new MBR partition table. This should provide you a GPT partition table ready for UEFI boot. (I know the installer can handle GPT because my 3TB+ disks were correctly formatted that way.)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I had the same problem and I have found a way to solve it, I made a post about it:

> [Troubleshoot problems with screen resolution (graphics) in GNU/Linux installers (Grub)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657983/troubleshoot-problems-with-screen-resolution-graphics-in-gnu-linux-installers/657984#657984)

I hope this will help many people and that developers will stop using predefined grub resolutions.