# Troubleshoot problems with screen resolution (graphics) in GNU/Linux installers (Grub)

Tags: boot, system-installation, grub, graphics

[image]
This problem shown in the image above is due to the fact that the default screen resolution of Grub (Linux boot menu) does not match the graphics resolution of the PC where you want to install the distro.

Grub tries to use a lower resolution than the one set by the computer and the graphics card instead forces the default resolution of the screen, creating that empty space on the right side of grub menu and causing the installation screen to stretch, making it unreadable and causing one to desist from installing Linux on his PC...

Personally I suffered from this on my Acer TravelMate P253 laptop with Intel HD 4000 graphics, it does not seem to be a very common bug, I have searched a lot in forums, there were people with other laptops that had the same problem and did not find a solution that worked (like me)...

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question, but **don't put the answer IN the question**.  Write the question, then post an answer.  You can post two answers if you want an English and Spanish version (U&L is officially English-only....but I doubt if anyone's going to object to a bonus non-English answer), or just post both English and Spanish versions in the one answer.   IMO, it would be better to have just one answer with both english and spanish text under each image, just to minimise the number of images on the page.

Comment: @cas 
1. converted the guide into a question.
2. let's say someone has the same bug, but he is not English speaking, the first thing he does is to search in Google, in the results will appear indexed my guide in this page (hope so), which I think is the best place to post problems and solutions related to Linux, it will help him to understand and solve the problem (that's what this page is for), besides he will know the Linux StackExchange community, I see no problem to have made a translation, anyway, thanks for the advice, my best wishes to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the Grub resolution value before installation, ***you only need to modify one file***, it can be done by **(A)** decompressing the .iso, modifying the file and then compressing it back to .iso or **(B)** directly on the installation media (assuming it is on a USB pendrive). I have tried method **(B)**.

For **(B)** I suggest to use *Rufus* or *Gnome MultiWriter* (in GNU/Linux), I also suggest to burn in **"hybrid iso"** mode (Rufus will ask you before burning) because burning in "DD" mode can make this operation more difficult...

For this example, I used Android Bliss (Android-x86 for PC), but it is similar with any Linux distro....

### STEPS TO FOLLOW:

0. Open the unzipped .iso or the prepared installation media.
   [image: *image]
1. **ATTENTION!** We must locate a file of format **".cfg"**, there are 2 of these .cfg files, one is called *"grub.cfg"* and **the other generally has the name of the distro**, for example *"android.cfg"* or *"grub_void.cfg"*, **the last one is the one that we need to edit** because it contains the resolution and theme values, in my case (Android Bliss) this file is located in *efi/boot/android.cfg*, in other distros like Void Linux, it is located in the *boot/grub* folder together with *grub.cfg*
   [image: *image]
2. Open the .cfg file with a text editor.
   [image: *image]
3. Once inside, search for the line **"set gfxmode="**, by default it usually appears with the resolution 1024x768, **we must change this value to the resolution of our screen**, in my case it is 1366x768, you can also try with the value *"auto"*, it is supposed that it will detect the resolution and it will establish it automatically, but it will be a question of trying...
   [image: *image]
4. Once modified with the value with our resolution, we save the file.
5. Ready, you can try again the installation.

I hope this guide is of your utility, you can leave your comment and/or contribution :)

[Similar Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371006/glitchy-debian-install-screen-both-standard-and-graphical)
[Link to the first image](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?38276-Problems-with-installing-Kali-Linux)

Comment: Te  escribo aquí por si a caso no ves mi comentario en tu respuesta borrada. Muchisimas gracias por tomar el tiempo para traducir tu respuesta, pero aquí solo se puede escribir en Ingles. Es lo que hay. Sin embargo, quizás te interesaría el el [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) donde si que se puede postear en castellano.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a postearlo por ahí también